# Jextract WinUser.h

Tags: java, project-panama

I am trying to use Jextract of project panama jdk22-ea

When I run
`jextract WinUser.h`

Then I get the following error:

`ERROR: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnt.h:173:2: error: "No Target Architecture"`

How can I use Jextract to get all functions from User32.dll?

Comment: This is a consequence of how the Windows header files are structured. Most of these header files can not be included directly. Instead, `Windows.h` should be included. You can see this when looking at one of the functions in `winuser.h`, for instance [AnimateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow). In the table at the bottom it says: `Header: winuser.h (include Windows.h)`

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use jextract with your own header that sets up suitable target architecture definitions. Try `User32.h` which simply contains:

```
#include <shlobj_core.h>
```

Then run jextract to determine all the symbols from your chosen header file as  `ALL.sym`:

```
jextract -luser32 -t mypackage --output generated.src User32.h --dump-includes ALL.sym
```

This gives 50,000+ linesof symbols - far too big to use if you compiled the extracted code. Instead, filter just to the definitions you plan to use by adding `--include-xyz ABC` parameter per symbol. It is easier to save the included symbols into a separate file such as `User32.sym`:

```
--include-function EnumWindows
--include-constant FALSE
--include-constant MAX_PATH 
--include-constant TRUE
```

Then run `jextract` with just the subset of symbols you need adding `--include-xyz ABC` or including the edited contents of `@User32.sym`:

```
jextract -luser32 -t mypackage --output generated.src User32.h @User32.sym
```

It may take a few iterations with copying lines from `ALL.sym` to `User32.sym` to get the right subset of dependencies.